# How do I find the network ip using docker and travis?

Tags: networking, docker, travis-ci

In my local setup, I can run ...

```
docker run --name myapp -e HOST=$(docker-machine ip default) --user root myapp
```

... and then use `$HOST` to connect to any other container (e.g. one running mongodb).

However, in Travis, `docker-machine` does not exist. Thus, I cannot simply put that line in my `.travis.yml`.

How do I get the network IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag `--link` adds an entry to `/etc/hosts` with the ip address of the specified running container

```
docker run --name myapp --link mongodb:mongodb myapp
```

However please note that:

> The default `docker0` bridge network supports the use of port mapping
>   and `docker run --link` to allow communications between containers in
>   the `docker0` network. These techniques are cumbersome to set up and
>   prone to error. While they are still available to you as techniques,
>   it is better to avoid them and define your own bridge networks
>   instead.

Another option is using the flag `--add-host` if you want to add a known ip address

```
docker run --name myapp --add-host mongodb:10.10.10.1 myapp
```

## Option 2

Create a network

```
docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 mynet123
```

Run mongodb container assigning an static ip

```
docker run --network mynet123 --ip 172.18.0.22 -d mongodb
```

Add that ip to the other container

```
docker run --network mynet123 --add-host mongodb:172.18.0.22 -d myapp
```

Comment: I thought `--link` were deprecated? Isn't that true?

Comment: Okay, I tried that and it works locally, so I'll test it on travis as well. Is there anything wrong with `docker run --name myapp --add-host=mongodb:127.0.0.1 --add-host=elasticsearch:127.0.0.1 myapp`?

Comment: `--add-host=mongodb:127.0.0.1` adds an alias to localhost, so this mapping seems to have no much sense, in that case use simply localhost

Comment: I still cannot get myapp to recognise the other containers ... even with linking. Do you have an idea why? It only does not work with travis ...